# TestClass Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I am getting the below error when running my test class and I am not sure why. With the debugging log it says that my controller is null. So when I do Controller.Save() it throws the error.

```
public with sharing class VF_CustomSave {

    private final sObject mysObject;

    // The extension constructor initializes the private member
    // variable mysObject by using the getRecord method from the standard
    // controller.
    public ApexPages.StandardController myController {get; set;}
    public VF_CustomSave(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {

    }

    public PageReference custom_save() {
        myController.save();        
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(Page.VF_SBQQ_Quoteline_TradeInView.getURL() );
        pageRef.getParameters().put('id',myController.getid());
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
    }
}
```

Test class

```
@isTest
Public Class VF_CustomSave_Test {

    Static TestMethod Void TestVF_CustomSave(){

         QuoteLine__c qli = new QuoteLine__c
             (
                 ListPrice__c = 1000.00,
             );

        insert qli;


         Test.startTest();

        system.debug(logginglevel.debug, 'DEBUG: START   ');


         PageReference pageRef = Page.VF_SBQQ_Quoteline_TradeInView;
         pageRef.getParameters().put('myController', String.valueOf(qli.Id));
         Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);


        system.debug(logginglevel.debug, 'pageRef  ' + qli.Id );


         ApexPages.StandardController scMyQouteLine = new ApexPages.StandardController(qli);
         system.debug(logginglevel.debug, 'scMyQouteLine  ' + scMyQouteLine);

         VF_CustomSave controller = new VF_CustomSave(scMyQouteLine);
         system.debug(logginglevel.debug, 'controller  ' + controller );
         controller.custom_save();

     Test.stopTest();



    }

}
```

Comment: I think in your test class we have to write like this:  pageRef.getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(qli.Id));

Comment: Nope it still says it null. 08:31:34:330 USER_DEBUG [71]|DEBUG|controller  VF_CustomSave:[myController=null, mysObject=null]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a pretty easy issue to solve. We can find the issue by "stepping through" (i.e. line x is executed, and then we go to the next line, and then we call this method, and in that method we...) the execution of your test in our heads.

```
VF_CustomSave controller = new VF_CustomSave(scMyQouteLine);
system.debug(logginglevel.debug, 'controller  ' + controller );
controller.custom_save();
```

First, we create a new instance of your controller, and we enter the constructor

```
public VF_CustomSave(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {

}
```

Your constructor doesn't do anything, so we return from the constructor.
We then debug, and after that, you call `custom_save()`.

```
public PageReference custom_save() {
    myController.save();        
    // Omitted the rest
}
```

The first line we execute here is `myController.save()`.
We can see that you do indeed have a controller property (i.e. a variable with a getter and setter) called `myController`, but *you haven't given this variable a value in your test*.
Thus, `myController` is null, and you receive your NullPointerException.

Fixing this is simply a matter of populating `myController` before you call your save method. Since it is a public property, you could set it directly in your test class (i.e. `controller.myController = <value>`). The more appropriate way to do this would probably be to update your constructor to actually take the `ApexPages.StandardController` that you're passing in to it, and assign that to `myController`.

Comment: What would you set the actual Controller value to be because i thought that i was setting my controller to be the standard controller with the qli

Comment: @Brooke That's a pretty basic follow-up question, and one that I'm loathe to answer directly (I feel that you'll get more out of working this out yourself rather than me telling you directly). Do you have an idea of what you might assign to that variable? What if it were something simpler like, say, an `Integer`. How would you assign a value to that? Lastly, look again at the last sentence of my answer. That should provide a decent hint.

Comment: Got it. Thanks - controller.myController = new ApexPages.StandardController(qli);

Comment: @Brooke That's one way, yes, but I think the better option here is to add a single line to your constructor to take the input parameter `stdController` and assign that to `this.myController`. The visualforce page/button that actually uses this controller of yours won't have the luxury of being able to set `myController` directly, and will be relying on your constructor to do that for it instead.